# How to make Perl scripts get executed only while user clicks on link/button etc

Tags: perl, http

I have few Perl scripts those gets execute even if we pass the URL in browser address bar. I just want to stop this behavior. What i want is when user clicks on button or link on which scripts are attached then only they should get execute.

```
www.example.com/cgi-bin/abc.cgi --- Should not work.

<button on-click="/cgi-bin/abc.cgi"> Execute me </button> -- it should work
```

How to do this?

Comment: You basically want application server to decide whether to call or not the script. Good luck with that.

Comment: This smells suspiciously like an X-Y Problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What are you actually attempting to accomplish by blocking users from manually entering the URL?

Comment: So what should happen when the URL is typed in the address bar?

Answer (score 4):

You can do that, there are two ways to go about it.
One, when buttons are clicked you can submit a form using the POST method, and the code should only be execute when the script is invoked using the POST method, e.g.:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/abc.cgi"><input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Execute me"><form>
```

Perl code:

```
if($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq 'POST') {
   ## execute special code
}
```

Two, you can check for an parameter in the query string:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Execute me" onClick="window.location.href='/cgi-bin/abc.cgi?doExecute=1';">
```

Perl:

```
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

if(defined $cgi->param('doExecute') && $cgi->param('doExecute')) {
   ## execute special code
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the second suggestion is easily foiled by users typing the parameter into the address bar along with the URL.

Comment: You can also just give a `name` attribute to the `<button>` and check that using `$cgi->param`. The `value` attribute will be its value. But @Dave's argument still applies.

Comment: One can combine (1) and (2). And then read about several programs that emulate POST from the CLI.